# Assign variable using multiple lines

Tags: bash, newlines, assignment

I have a function

```
f(){
    echo 777
}
```

and a variable to which I assign the "return value" of the function.

```
x=$(f)
```

Very concise! However, in my real code, the variable and function names are quite a bit longer and the function also eats positional arguments, so that concise line above, gets very long. Since I like to keep things tidy, I would like to break the code above in two lines.

```
x=\
$(f)
```

Still works! But: keeping things tidy also means respecting the indentation, so that gives something like

```
if foo
    x=\
    $(f)
fi
```

which does not work anymore due to whitespaces! Is there a good workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the value in `$_`, which is set to the last argument:

```
if foo; then
    : "$(f)"
    x=$_
fi
```

Or can use a subshell to eat the indent:

```
if foo; then
    x=$(
    )$(f)
fi
```

Comment: The second and third solutions are nice! The first one not so much. I assume this is why you got a downvote, which is completely unnecessary. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @pfnuesel It's a long story; basically, I thought of it first, posted it, realized the problem and added the note, got downvoted while thinking/searching for other solutions, then added the others. I'm not entirely sure why I didn't delete it after that (partially because the subshell was unquoted, anyway, I guess), but I've removed it now. Thanks for the accept!

Comment: Why use two subshells if you already have one?

Comment: @Ruslan Well, it crossed my mind, but then it slipped right out of it. You want Gilles' answer.

Answer (score 11):

Why go for complex, hard-to-read constructs? There is a perfectly natural way to present this which doesn't need any intermediate assignments, fancy ways of building an empty string, quoting subtleties or other cognitive burden.

```
if foo; then
    x=$(
      a_very_long_command_name --option1='argument 1 is long' \
                               --option2='argument 2 is long as well'
    )
fi
```

Comment: This! To put the opening parenthesis *before* the line break is what I see in style guides for most programming languages anyway. Look at [these examples from PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#multiline-if-statements) for instance.

Comment: So obvious. Funny how we all got very creative, while the solution was this simple.

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use here-docs, the following style works good. Quoting the here-doc string with a leading `-` allows your code to be intended with tabs *only*.

Something like

```
if true; then
        read -d '' -r x <<-EOF
        $(f)
        EOF
fi
```

But remember copy pasting the code from above doesn't work as Stack Exchange replaces tabs with spaces. You need to carefully type in the <kbd>Tab</kbd> character for the lines starting with the here-doc and the lines ending the here-doc. My `vim` configuration has mapped the tab character to 8 spaces. If you want to make it even neater, modify the spacing rule in `vim` by setting the spacing for tab to 4 spaces as `:set tabstop=4`

You can see how the <kbd>Tab</kbd> is formatted in my script, by looking into it using `sed`

```
$ sed -n l script.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash$
$
$
f(){$
    echo 777$
}$
$
if true; then$
\tread -d '' -r x <<-PERSON$
\t$(f)$
\tPERSON$
fi$
$
echo $x$
```

Notice the `\t` characters in the here-doc string above. If your script looks any different than the above, you would see the whining unexpected `EOF` errors.

Comment: Very nice! Had to read it like three times, to see where `x` is assigned.

Answer (score 2):

Why split the line at the equals sign?  You can just set the arguments to the function in a separate variable:

```
unset args
args+='arg1 '
args+='arg2 '
args+='arg3 '
x=$(f $args)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the arguments contain whitespace or characters that the shell interprets as wildcards. [You can't store a list of arguments in a string variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

Comment: Considering that this is about Bash you could use an actual array to deal with escaping issues: `cmd=(f /*line break*/ "arg1" /*line break*/ "arg2" ... ); x="$("${cmd[@]}")"`

Comment: He said the arguments are positional. Whitespace would break it anyways.